# How to automate a task on remote server. How can I take value from one response to be added in next command?

Tags: bash, curl, ssh, azure-blob-storage

I want to transfer old db_backups to some cold storage(Azure blob storage). How can I automate the task to transfer the files when the size reaches some specific limit, all ths should be done on remote server which I access through ssh in terminal.

Also how to read the response from which I can extract access_token and
can use that in my next command to be run automatically.
can anyone give me some example regarding this or any article to read?

How to add curl post request in bash script?

```
curl -X POST 'https://server.domain.com/v2/jobs/28723316-9373-44ba-9229-7c796f21b099/runs?project_id=aff59748-260a-476e-9578-b4f4a93e7a92' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H "Authorization: Bearer $token"  -d ''
```

output is something like this :

```
{
    "keys": [
        {
            "keyName": "key1",
            "value": "FD0o1y8eSPutze",
            "permissions": "FULL"
        },
        {
            "keyName": "key2",
            "value": "RLQ59xAi8Eg6p8VpIYx",
            "permissions": "FULL"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to know how the above command will be run in a shell script. I want to take key1 value from the response and echo it.

but right now I am having trouble in adding $token in the bearer authorization.
can anyone tell me the right format for this in shell script.

Comment: This is pretty vague. Maybe you could [edit] your question to show the actual commands that you need to run, the input that they normally take, and the output that they normally produce.

Comment: @Kenster, I have edited the question, thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm having difficulty working out if you are asking how to make a POST with `curl`, or how to parse JSON, or something about `ssh`, or something about limits in `azure`. Could you try to improve and clarify your question please?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I want to know the script shell for this curl post, and I want to store the response in a variable.

Comment: `$?` is the status of the last command that has run.  You can parse the answer using `jq`.  The result of a command can be stored in a variable using `$()`.  That will get you started on your research.